# Hadoop heap allocation

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am having issues with Hadoop 2.5.1 not increasing the heap space increase that I am requesting. Hadoop doesn't seem to be respecting the mapred.child.java.opts property in the mapred-site.xml file.

In my job I am doing the following:

```
R = new int[height * width];
G = new int[height * width];
B = new int[height * width];
```

Depending on the size of the image I pass job crashes saying

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Which is understandable. I need to increase the heap space but for some reason Hadoop doesn't want to respect the change in my mapred-site.xml file.

I added this to my mapred-site.xml and restarted

```
 <property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx12072m</value>
 </property>
```

When that didn't work I added this to my mapred-env.sh and restarted

```
export HADOOP_JOB_HISTORYSERVER_HEAPSIZE=4000
```

When that didn't work I added this to my yarn-env.sh and restart

```
JAVA_HEAP_MAX=-Xmx4000m
```

When that didn't work I added this to my yarn-env.sh and restart

```
YARN_HEAPSIZE=4000
```

When that didn't work I added this to my hadoop-env.sh and restart

```
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=4000
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_INIT_HEAPSIZE="3000"
```

I have restarted using start/stop-dfs.sh start/stop-all.sh start/stop-yarn.sh with their combinations. I have restarted the server and I have yet to see a change make a difference.

I am at a loss of what I can do or what else I can change.

Is there any way I can determine the heap size from within the job so I can try to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the actual original problem was but apparently it was a configuration issue I had on my end. Either a misconfiguration or a conflicting configuration that caused the issue. What I ended up doing was scratching the hadoop install and starting from scratch.

I followed the instructions for Pseudo-Distributed Operation in this guide:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

In addition to the configuration settings given in those instructions I added the following. You can find the information here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx4096m</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
 </property>
```

I do not have a reduce phase so I don't have to worry about those parameters.

The job seems to complete now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Xmx12072m"
```

I see you have already tried changing the mapred-site.xml (which was my other option).

How about if you try with a lower value first and see if it works??.

Probably you don't have enough RAM available for Java and you are trying to give more than it can reach. If this is the case then you will need to move to a machine having more memory and try there.

Good luck!

Comment: I did try your suggestion as well but that didn't work either. The machine has 64GB of memory so I was just trying to rule out lack of memory as the issue. With the size of the image I was trying to process it should have only needed ~800MB of memory.

Comment: I posted what I did as an answer.